# Launch a Library Activity From Project Manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest

Hi I have an activity defined in my Library like so...

```
<activity
            android:name="com.company.application.corelibrary.recording.DesiredActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_tracking"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

I then want to use this library to launch with in another application which I am doing like so...

```
<activity
        android:name="com.company.application.corelibrary.recording.DesiredActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_tracking"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

However when I am going to build it it comes back with...

```
[2013-02-27 12:41:33 - TestApplication] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.company.application/.corelibrary.recording.DesiredActivity }
[2013-02-27 12:41:33 - TestApplication] ActivityManager: Error type 3
[2013-02-27 12:41:33 - TestApplication] ActivityManager: Error: Activity class {com.company.application/com.company.application.corelibrary.recording.DesiredActivity} does not exist.
```

`com.company.application` is my project package.

`com.company.application.corelibrary` is my library package.

I have included the library in my project.

What am I doing wrong?

**ADDITION**

I just renamed my library project's package name to something different than that of my project as I thought maybe as they were similar the project may look in it own source for the class but this did not work either.

Comment: Can you full post both manifests?

Comment: Did you include `com.company.application.corelibrary`?

Comment: Did you specify the library as an Android library project or just in the normal Java build-path? From the manifest I can see no error

Comment: I have specified the project as a Library and included it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I would answer my own question. The other answers may be valid but this is what solved mine.

Before my activity declaration in the new projects manifest I had the following which was causing issues.

```
<uses-library
   android:name="com.corecoders.st.corelibrary"
   android:required="true" />
```

I removed that, cleaned and rebuilt the project and it launched fine.

Answer (score 0):

in my application, i have wrote activity in manifest like:

```
    <activity android:name="MainActivity"
             android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

i have also declare another activity (which activity belongs to my library) in the manifest as:

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

hope this will help u.

**N.B:**

u should not use

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

for two activity in a manifest.

Comment: Just to add to the last point, if there are two ``Main`` activities in an Android app, two icons will be created on the device when the application is installed.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by implemeting he solution io.card does in their library. By wrapping with the application tags the activities into your library manifest.

```
<application>
    <activity
        android:name="com.eckoh.eckohroute.ActionConsumingActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Dialog.ActionActivity" />

 </application>
```